# Best practices for exporting mongo collections to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, mongodb

we are using MongoDB (on Linux) as our main database. However, we need to periodically (e.g. nightly) export some of the collections from Mongo to a MS SQL server to run analytics.

I am thinking about the following approach:

1. Backup the Mongo database (probably from a replica) using mongodump
2. Restore the database into a Windows machine where Mongo is istalled
3. Write a custom made app to import the collections from Mongo into SQL (possibly handling any required normalization).
4. Run analytics on the Windows SQL Server installation.

Are there any other *"tried and true"* alternatives?

Thanks,
 Stefano

**EDIT**: for point 4, the analytics is to be run on SQL Server, not Mongo.

Comment: Your steps sound fine to me. Another alternative would be to import to MySQL on the original machine, do a SQL dump, and then import the SQL on the windows machine (assuming it's all standard SQL between them). Either way works, depends on whether you want MySQL on the original server or Mongo on the target server.

Answer (score 3):

Overall looks fine, but i can suggest two things:

1. Skip backup/restore steps and read data directly from linux mongodb, because it will be harder and harder to backup/restore database as it will grow.
2. Instead of custom made app use [Quartz.net](http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/) for nightly export, it is easy to use and can solve any other schedule tasks.

Also i can suggest look into such new approaches as [cqrs and event sourcing](http://codebetter.com/gregyoung/2010/02/13/cqrs-and-event-sourcing/), that's basically allow to avoid export tasks. You can just handle messages and store data into two data sources (linux mongodb, windows sql server) in real time with small delay, or even analyze data from messages and store in mongodb.

Comment: wouldn't it be possible that reading data directly from a live instance could harm data integrity (especially if the operation spans across a few minutes)? What if data is changed when the copy is in progress?

Comment: @StefanoRicciardi: I don't see how you can break data integrity when reading data. Even if you reading it 5 days. It's okay when data get changed while you read it, in any way you will run analytics on a stale data.

Comment: In fact I am concerned on the integrity of the _target_ data, not of the source. Suppose I am sweeping collection A, where an item a references to an item b from collection B. Meanwhile b gets deleted from the source and when I am ready to copy collection B item b is not there anymore.

Comment: Just to add that this integrity problem seems to be handled by the mongodump via the "--oplog" parameter, but I wonder how that should be tackled with a live read from a server.

Comment: @StefanoRicciardi: I see. With backup/restore strategy you can also break data integrity, because it does not lock database. But you can use  `db.runCommand({fsync:1,lock:1})` to prevent writes while you reading/backuping data. Or most simple solution it's stop your server. But i would go with another solution: event if for some `a` item `b` is not present you can just skip it and not add to sql database.

Comment: I'd read all data from a slave, as doing a full table scan (which is reading all data) while not your whole data set fits in memory will degrade performance a lot.

Comment: @Derick: you mean read from a slave as in "do a mongodump from a slave" or read live data from a slave from a custom app feeding SQL Server?